Technical Report Documentation Page: Complex Table in Overleaf?
all -- I am wondering if there is a good way to make a technical report documentation page page, which is something like this: at least four columns wide, but some cells have been merged, and not all columns are the same width, and lots of text in the columns (see attached image for an example). Any tips or templates you'd recommend?


Welcome to TeX SE. What have you tried? There is a variety of package that can do that. A mix of \multicolumn and \multirow, the nicematrix package, drawing it with tikz, etc

Additionally, the p column type allows you to specify a width and then the text has appropriate line breaking within that column.

note that overleaf is just your editor so the tag is irrelevant here. overleaf's documentation on tables is good (but don't use !h as the optional argument to table, as it doesn't make sense, imho, and isn't a good idea at all). I'd recommend not using a template period.

Here is a draft using tabularray
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
  
  \begin{tblr}{width=0.8\linewidth,
      colspec={XXX},
      vlines,
      hlines,
      cells={l,h},
      cell{2}{1}={r=2,c=2}{},
      cell{5}{1}={r=2,c=2}{},
      cell{7}{1}={r=2,c=2}{},
    }
    1. Report No. & 2. Gov No. & 3. Recipient No.\\
    4. {Title\\ A long text\\with line break} & & 5. Date\\
    & & 6. Performing code\\
    \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{} 7. Authors & & 8. Performing No.\\
    9. Name adress & & 10. Work unit no.\\
    & & 11. Contract No.\\
    12. Sponsoring & & 13. Type of report\\
    & & 14. Agency code\\
    \SetCell[r=1,c=3]{} 15. Notes & & \\
    \SetCell[r=1,c=3]{} 16. Abstract &&\\
  \end{tblr}
  
\end{document}



In OP, it looks like width(col2) < width(col1) < width(col3).  But otherwise, this looks good.

@Teepeemm in that case, use colspec={X[1]X[2]X[3]}, for instance
